# DirectShow Filter error "Class is not registered"

Tags: c++, com, directshow, regsvr32, graphedit

Using the following code under my cpp/win32 project I get error "class is not registered"

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_PIAsyncFile, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**) &ppF);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

  hr = pGraph->AddFilter(ppF, L"My Async Source (File)");

}
```

This is not true,since my filter works just fine under GraphEdit and I can also find it using IFilterMapper2 enumerating monikers. I can also bind to object from the direct show filters successfully.

```
hr = pMoniker->BindToObject(0, 0, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&ppF);
```

So, what's wrong with the *CoCreateInstance* ?

PS:This is a 32bit filter that registered under a 64Bit Windows 7 system. In the registry I can also find the filter under sysWOW3264 (a mirror registry for 32-bit windows apps running on 64bit windows).

You can also refer and find the source code to my codeproject post at http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/4603967/Class-not-registered-error.aspx

Comment: There is no magic: 0x80040154 `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` "Class not registered" means registration problem. That is, you pass wrong CLSID or something related like bitness issue. Debugging can show this, otherwise it's more a guess work. Your screeshot confirms there is a registration entry. It does not confirm GraphEdit can actually instantiate it.

Comment: Hi,
I can confirm that GraphEdit can actually instantiate it and it works fine. How can I debug this procedure ?

Comment: `1` Visually inspect registry keys starting from HKCR\CLSID\<your-key> `2` compare CLSID displayed by GraphEdit to yours you use from code `3` use `ProcMon` to check what registry activity takes place when you attempt to instantiate `4` once again make sure it's not 32/64 bitness issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Roman R, the problem was the wrong CLSID declaration in my code.